# Convert LAS tool hangs at 2%

Tags: arcgis-pro, lidar, las, laz

I'm trying to convert LiDAR data from .LAZ to .LAS using the Convert LAS tool in ArcGIS Pro, but it always stops at 2% and is never able to complete the decompression. Does anyone have any thoughts regarding what may cause this to happen or experienced similar issues?

I'm able to decompress them in LasTools, so I know the files aren't corrupt. I'm well aware that I could just use LasTools for this process, but my company computer is locked down pretty tight by the admin so I can only use LasTools on another computer (which lacks the ArcGIS Pro license). This adds an extra step and a lot of time to my workflow, so I'm trying to solve the issue in ArcGIS Pro if possible.

Comment: You don't need admin privilege to use lastools

Comment: Mind blown. Problem solved. LasTools still won't run it as a tool in ArcGIS pro's toolbox, and my command prompt is disabled, but the Run dialogue still works. Thanks!